# How to test mongodb save() method failure?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, error-handling

I have a working script, and in my node code, I have instances of `save()`, like the following:

```
user.remove(function(error, removedMeasurement) {
    if (error) {...} else {...}
});
```

I would like to confirm that something is done when handling an error during the `save()`. I tried killing my connection to the db after I started the process, but then the process just hangs without error.

My connection to the db is similar to 
`db = mongoose.createConnection(connectionToDb, options);`

and the options include:

```
reconnectTries:60,
reconnectInterval:2000
```

If I restart the db connection right away, the script will continue, so I think the above attribute options have something to do with this, and so killing the db connection does not help trigger the error to confirm I am handling it correctly.

Comment: Why don't you do the same? user.save(function(error, result) {})

Comment: Thanks, the issue was more about how to trigger the error because killing the db was not doing it. One way was to change the object being saved, e.g. remove some attribute required by the schema, and this actually worked to create the error.